# Enabling a custom richcombo plugin to CKEditor

Tags: 7, wysiwyg

I'm trying to enable my custom CKEditor plugin in Drupal, but the custom dropdown is never shown.

I'm using [CKEditor](https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor) module.

Here's what I did:

1. I created a new folder in `/ckeditor/plugins` and saved my code in `plugin.js` file.
2. The plugin became visible under "Editor appearance". I enabled it in `/admin/config/content/ckeditor/edit/%my_profile`.
3. The plugin file is loaded, but the `init` method is never invoked and my dropdown is never added to the toolbar.

Here is the code of my plugin:

```
(function() {
  console.log('custom_richcombo plugin.js loaded');
  CKEDITOR.plugins.add('custom_richcombo', {
    requires: ['richcombo'],
    init: function(editor) {
      console.log('custom_richcombo plugin initialized');
      var config = editor.config;
      editor.ui.addRichCombo('editorLinksCombo', {
        label: 'Custom dropdown',
        title: 'Custom dropdown title',
        multiSelect: false,
        init: function() {
          this.startGroup('Test group');
          this.add(1, 'Option 1', 'Title for option 1');
          this.add(2, 'Option 2', 'Title for option 2');
          this.add(3, 'Option 3', 'Title for option 3');
        },
        onClick: function(optionID) {
          console.log('Clicked on option', optionID);
        },
      });
    }
  });
})();
```

This works perfectly fine on a standalone CKEditor installation.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: I came here looking for an answer to this exact question.